# Generic method returning different types

Tags: c#, .net, generics, nullable

I am learning c# generics and I ran into a "problem". (At least, I think it is a problem).

I have a program where I am parsing some options and storing their values in Dictionaries and I think my implementation of `GetValue` method is a bit crappy:

```
public class Parser
    {
        private Dictionary<Option, string?> optionsParametersString = new();
        private Dictionary<Option, int?> optionsParametersInt = new();
        private Dictionary<Option, bool?> optionsParametersBool = new();
        
        public T? GetValue<T>(Option option)
        {
            if (option.parameterType == typeof(string))
            {
                if(optionsParametersString[option] == null) return default(T);
                else return (T?)Convert.ChangeType(optionsParametersString[option], typeof(T));
            }
            else if (option.parameterType == typeof(int))
            {
                if (optionsParametersInt[option] == null) return default(T);
                else return (T?)Convert.ChangeType(optionsParametersInt[option], typeof(T));
            }
            else if (option.parameterType == typeof(bool))
            {
                if (optionsParametersBool[option] == null) return default(T);
                else return (T?)Convert.ChangeType(optionsParametersBool[option], typeof(T));
            }
            else throw new Exception();
            
        }
    }
```

`Option` is a class with some other properties (parameterType, name...) but I think it is not important now.

And the problem is, that I can't think of any better solution than this... I thought about having just one Dictionary with `object` values and converting those object to type `T`, but I would like to store `int` as `int` and not as object.

Is there a way how to implement this better ? (Without type switching and weird converting like `(T?)Convert.ChangeType(optionsParametersString[option], typeof(T))`).

Thanks for any suggestions and help.

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: Seems like there should be 3 overloads of `GetValue`, with different names.

Comment: If `Option` knows the type then it really should be generic as well `Option<T>` then you'd infer the type from that on the `GetValue` method.  Otherwise you can do something like `GetValue<stirng>(IntOption)`.  Also consider using `TryGetValue` instead of `if (optionsParametersBool[option] == null)` because that's going to throw if the key is not in the dictionary, rather than return null.

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do? If it is parsing command line options you might want to take a look at the [Command line parser library](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline)